# How to center a text under an image regardless of the size of that text

Tags: html

Let's say I have an Image.

```
<img src="lala.png" />
```

This image has a `width=400px;`.

and I want to type "Lala" under this Image.

```
<img src="lala.png" />
<br>
<span>Lala</span>
```

Note that I'm gonna be fetching those images and those texts from a database, the width of the images is fixed at 400px, but of course the texts will vary in size, so I can't use `margin-left:100px;` to push the text to the middle because It will look wrong on other texts...

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: If your image is always `400px` in `width`, why not create a div underneath your image which is also `400px` in `width`, with a `text-align:center;` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by `text-align:center;`

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
<img src="lala.png" />
<br>
<span>Lala</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when the text, set on one line, is wider than the image?

Comment: Yes, or setting `width`, but the point is that without such settings, the text will occupy available width and that you would need to hard-wire a specific width.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a div instead of span.

HTML:

```
<div class="underImage">Blah</div>
```

Style:

```
.underImage {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the image and text in an element and use the text-align CSS attribute on the wrapping element.

HTML

```
<p class="center-wrapper">
 <img src="lala.png" />
 <br>
 <span>Lala</span>
</p>
```

CSS

```
.center-wrapper { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [several ways](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/captions.html) to achieve that, but the most flexible and most effective way is to use a one-cell table, with the caption text in a `caption` element:

```
<table class="image">
<caption align="bottom">caption text</caption>
<tr><td><img ...></td></tr>
</table>
```

There are many people who oppose such use of a table on quasi-religious grounds, but it’s still the flexible way that does not require you to set the width of the text explicitly (as opposite to letting it be determined by the width of the image) and works independently of CSS support.